# Open interval a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, vectors, normed-spaces

I have the following question: Is the open interval $\left(-1,1 \right)\subset \mathbb{R}$ a vector space in itself, or is it simply a metric space?

Attemps at understanding:

> I get the feeling that $\left(-1, 1 \right)$ fails to be a vector space, as it fails to close under scalar multiplication by any $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, namely it should be true that for all $v\in (-1,1)$, $\lambda v\in (-1,1)$ and this is obviously not the case.

My next question is the following: can we consider $(-1,1)$ to be locally a vector space? Does the idea of a local vector space make any sense?If yes, what would be the precise definition of it?

Comment: "Local" vector spaces don't make much sense to me. Perhaps your notion of "local" vector spaces is just that of open subsets in a vector space.

Comment: Where is $0.75+0.75$?

Comment: So if I have a *linear* map $T:V \mapsto W$, with $V$ and $W$ vector spaces, and I decide to restrict the domain to some open set $A\subset V$, then the restricted map $T_{res}:A \to W$ ceases to be linear? Not even locally?

Comment: It could be considered a "convex space" (not sure of the exact terminology): it has convex linear combinations $\lambda_1 x_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n x_n$ where $\lambda_i \ge 0, \lambda_1 + \cdots + \lambda_n = 1$.

Comment: @Randall obviously it fails to close under addition too. Thanks.

Comment: What properties of the space are you hoping to preserve?  The interval is going to fail nearly all of the axioms of a vector space, but it is still a smooth manifold, retains its total ordering, and (as you noted) has the structure of a metric space.  Is there some specific algebraic structure that you want to retain? or are there other structures that you are hoping for?

Comment: @XanderHenderson In the definition of the continuity of a function, the domain seems to always be an open set (i.e. not a vector space, *why*??). How can we then  say, $f(x)\to f(a)$ (as $x \to a$) : for all $\varepsilon >0$ there exists $\delta(\varepsilon)>0$ such that for all $x\in A$ ($A$ open interval)$ |x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$? My point being that we can't define $x-a$ when the open interval is not a vector space.

Or could it be that then we use the metric $d(x,y)$ instead of the norm $|  \cdot |$ for the domain?

Comment: @EEEB This is because the concept of continuity is a topological concept, which does not require an underlying vector space, only an underlying topological space.  In $\mathbb{R}$, the metric provides this structure.  As you note, we could replace $|x-a|$ with $d(x,a)$, and the proofs would go through identically.  Indeed, we can generalize this even more to a fairly abstraction notion of an "open set"  (and thus TOPOLOGY is born!).

Comment: @XanderHenderson Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

An open interval $(0,1)$ threated as a subspace of $\mathbb R$ (inheriting operations from the larger set) isn't a vector space over field of real numbers, because $1/2 \in (0,1)$, but $1/2 + 1/2 = 1 \not \in (0,1)$, so it isn't closed under addition.

But there is a way to turn it into vector space. Observe that 
$$\tan \colon \left(-\frac \pi 2 , \frac \pi 2\right) \to \mathbb R$$
is a bijection. So if we define for $v, w \in (- \pi/2, \pi/2)$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb R$:
$$v \oplus w = \arctan(\tan v + \arctan w)$$
$$\lambda v = \arctan(\lambda \tan v),$$
the axioms of vector space are satisfied! Now just rescale and translate $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ onto $(0, 1)$.

I think that this construction is called **push forward** (like in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_measure).

Answering your second question: every point of $(0,1)$ has a neighbourhood that looks like an open ball in $\mathbb R$ (in fact, we can take whole space as that neighbourhood). Thus $(0,1)$ is an example of a manifold.

As a side note, $\mathbb R$ isn't the only completion of rational numbers $\mathbb Q$, because according to Ostrowski's theorem, there are other norms on $\mathbb Q$, $p$-adic norms, that make $\mathbb Q$ into topological metric space. In its completion, field of $p$-adic numbers $\mathbb Q_p$, closed unit ball $\mathbb Z_p = \{x \in \mathbb Q_p : |x| \le 1\}$ is also a ring, something you never wished to be true in case of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your feeling is right, as is your reason. There's no useful way to think of a "local vector space" but the idea of thinking about things locally is a useful intuition. Smooth curves are "locally lines", smooth surfaces are "locally planes". These ideas can and have been made formal; you will encounter them if you go on in mathematics.